# HTML/Jquery: div not detecting hover even when z-index set to highest?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I am having an odd problem - have a div within wrapper assigned to a class name here:

```
echo '<div class="about">Z&S</div>';
```

In my stylesheet, the wrapper around this div has a z-index of -1 but I have given .about a z-index of 5 (so it will definitely be above all other elements). I have even tried deleting the z index given to my wrapper but my problem still persists.

My problem is that I am trying to change content of div on hover using this script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("LOADED SCRIPT.JS");

    //Change creds text
    $(".about").hover(
        function() // on mouseover
        {


    console.log("RAN IT");
            $(this).text("This is the new html");
        }, 

        function() // on mouseout
        {
            $(this).text("Z&Snnn");

        });

});
```

I know this is executing because "LOADED" is printed to console. However I cannot change the div's text because .about is not detecting hover. The log within the hover function is not printed.

I've never had this before - why won't my div detect hover?

EDIT- I have tried:

```
$(".about").on("mouseover", function(){
 console.log("HELLO");
 })
```

and

```
$(document).on("mouseover",".about", function(){
            console.log("RAN IT");
            $(this).text("This is the new html");
});
```

Nothing is printed when I hover over it. I have also deleted the z index on my wrapper if that should affect anything

Comment: `$(document).on("mouseover",".about", function(){....})` try delegating event to document

Comment: I think its more of a event delegation problem rather the zindex

Comment: can you create a demo on jffiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try  `$(".about").on("mouseover", function(){})` maybe, but I think if you wrapper has -1 `z-index`, regardless of what your child `z-index` is, any sibling element to wrapper with a `z-index > -1` will still be over your wrapper's children (I think, sorry if I am wrong about that)

Comment: I have updated my question - I tried the 2 ways suggested yet the div is still not registering hover

Comment: it's difficult to determine without knowing what else you have done to the document really. What's the CSS of the div? It might be that the div is actually really small and the text is just overflowing. Try adding a width/height to this div and a border so you can visually see it. You could also try .html() instead of .text(), but that's not going to help if your console.log() isn't firing obviously.

Answer (score 0):

`z-index` is used with only `position` property.Use `hover()` method with two parameter passing as function for `mouseenter` and `mouseout`.I tried using hover if that helpful to You then check it on this [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/RTyOHm5vtaUAh27AZ6RT?p=preview)